# Is there a way to visualize the loss and accuracy of media pipe's image classifier?

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, mediapipe

I have trained a model using the media pipe `model = image_classifier.ImageClassifier.create(..)`. In order to plot and see the loss val_loss and accuracy and val_accuracy we need a history attribute. But there is no history attribute. In other lib like TensorFlow and TensorFlow model maker, they have a model. history attribute from where we can plot the graph easily.

Is there any way to plot the graph in the media pipe. Please guide me in this matter.

```
model = image_classifier.ImageClassifier.create(
    train_data = train_data,
    validation_data = validation_data,
    options=options,
)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

history_dict = model.history.history

### LOSS:
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
epochs = range(1, len(loss_values) + 1)
line1 = plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, label='Training Loss')
plt.setp(line1, linewidth=2.0, marker = '+', markersize=10.0)
plt.xlabel('Epochs') 
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

### ACCURACY:
acc_values = history_dict['accuracy']
epochs = range(1, len(loss_values) + 1)
line1 = plt.plot(epochs, acc_values, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.setp(line1, linewidth=2.0, marker = '+', markersize=10.0)
plt.xlabel('Epochs') 
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Error is Here:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2474e52497a7> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      3 
----> 4 history_dict = model.history.history
      5 
      6 ### LOSS:

AttributeError: 'ImageClassifier' object has no attribute 'history'
```

I have seen the documentation and they says

An instance based on ImageClassifier.

[API Docs To Media Pipe](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mediapipe_model_maker/image_classifier/ImageClassifier)

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but a solution nonetheless!

1. Generate your accuracy and loss values from training
   [image]
2. Copy the values into a pandas dataframe
   [image]

3.Create your graph(s)
[image]

4. Should look something like this
   [image]

Hope that helps!